# tensorflow2.0 isn't working with spyder with python 3.6

Tags: tensorflow, spyder

I had installed anaconda3.5.2 which installs python 3.6.10. I then installed tensorflow2.0.
After installation, from cmd console I get into python and import tensorflow as tf. I typed tf.**version** and all looks good. Then I launch spyder and do the same, the import does not give any errors, however tf.**version** says tf is not defined. I looked at sys.path and in both cases the paths are exactly the same.

Appreciate any help and an answer.

Comment: For clarification: How did you install tensorflow? Did you use pip install tensorflow in anaconda? Have you already tried "tf.__version__" instead?

Answer (score 1):

This can sometimes be the case if we install `Tensorflow` in the `Base Environment`.

Recommended way is to create a `Virtual Environment` in `Anaconda` and install the `Tensorflow` in that `Virtual Environment`, which works in most of the cases.

Using Virtual Environments has advantages like

- We can maintain multiple versions of `Tensorflow` in multiple `Virtual Environments` with each `Virtual Environment` comprising each `version` like `1.14, 1.15, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2,etc..`
- We can use different `Python Versions` (`2.x, 3.6, 3.7`) in each `Virtual Environment`
- If we want to modify the `source code` of any of the Tensorflow API, we can do it within our Virtual Environment, without impacting its functionality in other `Virtual Environments`.

Steps for Creating a New Virtual Environment and installing `Tensorflow` in `Anaconda`, for different Operating Systems, is shown below:

```
# Create a New Virtual Environment
conda create --name TF_2_VE

# When conda asks you to proceed, type y:
proceed ([y]/n)?

# Activate the Virtual Environment. Conda Version > 4.6 
conda activate TF_2_VE

# Activating Virtual Environment, Conda Version < 4.6 and Windows OS
activate TF_2_VE

# Activating Virtual Environment, Conda Version < 4.6 and Linux and Mac OS
source activate TF_2_VE


# Install the TF Version you need
conda install tensorflow
```

The above command will install the `Latest Version` of `Tensorflow` (`2.2` as of now). If you want an older version like `2.0`, you can replace the last step of the above set of commands with

`conda install tensorflow==2.0`.

Hope this information helps. Happy Learning!