# Installing Tensorflow on win10 ( installed but showing error while doing import tensorflow as tf)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using Windows 10Pro [ss of my OS info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBtAP.png)
Using the latest version of Anaconda, python(version 3.8.3), TensorFlow version information as follows
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.0

I installed Tensorflow CPU.

While importing TensorFlow I have the following errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 40, in 
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Prakash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

[Screen shot of the error showning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUXIS.png)

please help me resolve this issue.
comment if any other information is needed

Comment: Hi Prakash, Is your issue resolved? If not, Did you try installing `Tensorflow` in a `New Virtual Environment` in `Anaconda`? Please refer the Stack Overflow Answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821746/11530462, for more details. Thanks!

Comment: If even creating a `New Virtual Environment` doesn't resolve your problem, please refer the Github Issue, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41258#issuecomment-656646960. Thanks!

Comment: @Prakash Khorasiya, Is your issue resolved? Else, please let us know current status of your issue, so that we can help you. Thanks!