# Tensorflow path-performance installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I've noticed that upon running my tensorflow, I have a spike on first few runs on start-up

upon searching on the internet, I came into this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-for-performance-sake-5854f9d9eb0c)

the replies and official documents got me even more confusing on which installation is best for performance.
Is it

1. [Conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)
2. [pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)
3. [docker](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker)
4. some others that are not listed?

My current setup is windows 10 laptop with GTX965M, tensorflow installation accordingly to this [guide](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-to-Install-TensorFlow-with-GPU-Support-on-Windows-10-Without-Installing-CUDA-1187/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=00a434eb5660ef9adde089637a3f758cf5dc3ae7-1597041278-0-Ab9a9JQOsV69Oavp4kL8vS-DWZEp5U_l9Fye2M1A58NsOsDCQ_uiPgnSTM66cOOvK0erlU_zP8ug8cmfA99wKT-TerwDtfhsxmewYK8GfBT6ZmXHC3tkt6M38aMnFuSRgYTB31aBGDms6llHaFDaNNXGoRoFgdSk511UTV32C8rj-XeRvVtn9ak-nvUgDeF0x-KTodHkaAr65akqFsPduxpdlzM6FVU66mLEujaZuaR-KYCnwsKA219nQs3HMFDFgZNKnbOUlC9mTKhWaj8ZUfUoJuikMmlh6FiVIDmi4vxDeh67yUMA09ocaHM04l5az7-VRbUYUaCO8p2mjUbK4bUW14kYtG5aQ8owkuNN4mnix5-IPLfRUSvxy0X6OxSITo4uGaVMy3j7AXglDQcHBSKiqQllA-qgkYAVVJ3tsOOttig4kDZjqZ2gFFBEj0k3KBDM9dBQzT7EoiCAS0IAMKkcCSDoUGOfpgghxFnLu_ek07RwZuzq0U6eITZQy-GtGpVNsmbpgQ6nQikYjqvq_RTFQB5auJp_TbfviwRh163Gt-DGCqVNkGi90_R0dCv1UxLQ_F28bZpZNTK-EemJM5afRBPZu37-6V8mt1DK81XgKBo1nBYZTGQFoZd8nZQhIw)

Another weird thing, my conda installation is only able to install tensorflow 1.8 for some reason. Upon running the code `conda update tensorflow`, it returns latest version has been installed. But I can install tensorflow 2 by stating `conda install tensorflow=2`. Is this normal? If not what could be the issue? (I have all the packages updated before 'updating/installing' tensorflow. Doesn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge creating a virtual environment in anaconda and install the Tensorflow in virtual environment has advantages.

Please refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821746/14290681) for the advantages and steps to create virtual environment.

> Upon running the code conda update tensorflow, it returns latest
> version has been installed. But I can install tensorflow 2 by stating
> conda install tensorflow=2. Is this normal?

Yes, this is a normal behavior.

[Google Colab](https://medium.com/tensorflow/colab-an-easy-way-to-learn-and-use-tensorflow-d74d1686e309) is an easy way to learn and use TensorFlow. It's a Jupyter notebook environment that requires no setup to use and runs entirely in the cloud.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get my point very clear. I was trying to install tensorflow on a virtual environment with the command `conda install tensorflow`. Weird thing is, it install 1.14 initially when clearly there's v2 available in the anaconda cloud. "Latest version has installed" is returned when I run `conda update tensorflow`. But I could install tensorflow  v2 by stating `conda install tensorflow=2`. Doesn't seem normal behavior to me tbh.